How to make an NMOS model SOAtherm compatible in LTSPICE
I am looking to do some thermal simulations for switching power MOSFETs. LTSPICE ships a small handful of NMOS parts that have thermal modelling parameters defined such that they can be used with the SOAtherm-Heatsink and SOAtherm-PCB components. It’s these components I’m most interested in making use of as part of thermally modelling my switching MOSFETs.
As a concrete example, say I was wanting to experiment with the IRFH7440 NMOS from Infineon. I'd like to be able to simulate its electrical behaviour, as well as interface it with an SOAtherm-PCB.  They provide SPICE models on the product page, however this model is not SOAtherm compatible. There is a separate thermal model embedded in the spice directive which can be used (see the image below), is there a way I can either:

Incorporate this information to make a single simulation component that can be used for electrical and thermal simulations (like the NMOS models that ship with LTSPICE that are SOAtherm compatible; OR

Use the thermal information to create a new component that will allow me to use the electrical model with the SOAtherm-HeatSink and SOAtherm-PCB components


I’m assuming option 1 is probably technically possible, however I’ve spent a bit of time googling and looking at the documentation and I don’t know where to begin – I don’t know what the internal parameters for the model are.
The second option is fine for my use case – I’d like to be able to seamlessly swap between electrical and thermal simulations.


There are two typical RC thermal models: the Foster and Cauer models.  These are called Tank and Filter models by Vishay, respectively.  However, the LTspice RC thermal model is something made by Dan Eddleman called "DanTherm".  I think some people tried to reverse engineer the "DanTherm" RC ladder model, but haven't gotten anywhere yet.  So I believe option 1 is not practical.

Option 2 might be doable but I don't know exactly how to modify the Foster model you have in your IRFH7440 subcircuit to interface with SOAtherm-PCB or SOAtherm-HeatSink.  You might just need to expose the Tc somehow, but I'm not sure how to do that.  I think your best bet would be to use an Option 3 where the manufacturers' models can be used directly.  Try looking both here and over here for more info on that.
